# ffmpeg : 4K BluRay to 1080p x264

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, blu-ray

I'm trying to encode a 1080p x264 from a 4K BluRay.  The problem is that source has bit-depth : 10 bits and i want output bit-depth 8 bits ...

3840x2160  *(input)* **==>** 3840x1600 *(cropped to delete black bars)* **==>** 1920x800 *(resized)*

If i use x264 0.155.2901 7d0ff22 compiled with bit-depth=all

```
ffmpeg -y -i input4K.m2ts -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -x264-params me=umh:merange=24:trellis=1:level=4.1:ref=5 -filter:v "crop=3840:1600:0:280, scale=1920:800" -an "1080_"$output.mkv
```

it works but the output file is not 8bit, **Format profile : High 10@L4.1**

how to get format profile = High @L4.1 ? (force 8 bits output)

If i usex264 compiled with bit-depth=8, it tells me it can't read source.

Comment: After scale, insert `format=yuv420p`

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

`ffmpeg -y -i input4K.m2ts -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow -crf 18 -x264-params me=umh:merange=24:trellis=1:level=4.1:ref=5 -filter:v "crop=3840:1600:0:280, scale=1920:800" -an "1080_"$output.mkv`